# Contact list how display as table

Tags: contact

For a menu item if I choose

- contact->featured contacts  **Display** = **table** view
- contacts->list all contacts in category  **Display** = **list** view

I cannot find anywhere this seems to be defined. 
How can I get a table for List all contacts in category?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the thing you are looking to define - assuming this is to select a table layout instead of the default list one.
But does it have to be a table?

The menu item **Contacts ->Lists all contacts in a category** will display a list of contacts from a selected category, that at least in the protostar template someone could say that it looks close to a table.

If a table layout is important you could create a template override to meet your specific layout desires.

I am lazy right now to search for resources (they are plenty) on how to create template overrides - so I leave this to you.

Comment: Yes I want a table layout rather than the default list layout.  I want to include the email for each contact and this appears below the contact name rather than in a separate column so the fomat is not suitable. I don't know how to create a template overwrite but will try to look for some simple instructions

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link on how to create a template override for protostar:

http://bj.zemplate.com/protostar-responsive-template/customization/21-creating-template-overrides

Create an override for the **com_contact** component: **category**.
I found it helpful to also create an override for the **com_contact** component: **featured** as well to use as a template.

The override files can now be found under the editor tab html folder. You need to edit the **com_contact/category/default_items.php** file.  You need to replace the whole **ul** section with a **table**.  You can copy the table from the **com_contact/featured/default_items.php** file.

You will probably need to apply some custom css to make it look how you want.